# Is there a standardised test about emotion perception?

Tags: emotion, test

I'm looking for a standardised psychological test to measure how people react to positive and negative emotions. More precisely I want to use such tests to investigate whether an individual is very tolerant against positive and negative emotions and does not perceive and shows them as intensively as other individuals.

I have seen that there are frustration tolerance tests, but I'm not interested in this specific emotion but more on general positive and negative emotions. I have also seen that there are tests to measure the emotional intelligence, and part of the emotional intelligence is the ability to assess one's own emotions. This would be okay for me, but I'm looking for a dedicated test into this direction.

I've also found tests (NEO FFI) to measure the big five personality traits and one could argue that some of these traits are linked to more openness towards emotions, but still, it's not a dedicated test.

So my question is, if there is a dedicated test for that?

Comment: "How people react to positive and negative emotions" is very broad; if you can narrow it down, it would be an easier question to answer.  Their own? Others? Physiologically? Verbally? etc.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is pretty broad at the moment. But a few starting points:

The PANAS is a commonly used measure of mood or well-being that asks respondents to rate how frequently they have experienced a set of positive and negative emotions.

Many broad-based personality measures such as those based on the Big 5 will have  have factors or facets that relate to emotional experience.

There are also a range of common emotional intelligence measures.

- The Mayer-Salovey-Caruso Emotional Intelligence Test (MSCEIT) is a popular ability based measure of emotional intelligence.
- There are also several self report (personality-style) measures of emotional intelligence: e.g., EQ-i, the Swinburne University Emotional Intelligence Test (SUEIT), and the Schutte EI model